# Why was Shun Kazami crying/devastated when he saw Shiori die from an illness?

Tags: bakugan

In Bakugan, Shun Kazami saw Shiori die from an illness. Shun was crying. Why was he devastated? Did he and Shiori love each other? Were they Related?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Bakugan Wiki](https://bakugan.fandom.com/wiki/Shiori_Kazami), Shiori was Shun's mother. So yes, they were related, hence Shun's emotional reaction.

Having said that, you don't have to be related to or in love with someone to be upset about their death, so the premise of your question seems a little odd to me.